# HERE Maps Starter SDK geoLocation of bounds of Visible Map

Tags: geolocation, here-api, heremaps-android-sdk

How can I tell if a GeoLocation position is in the visible area of map? Or how can I get the GeoLocations of the boundaries of the visible portion of the map.I am using the HERE SDK (Starter) for Android.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the visible portion of the map, you can try Map.getBoundingBox(), which Returns the current visible map area as a GeoBoundingBox.
Then, you can use GeoBoundingBox.contains(GeoCoordinate coord) to determine whether the specified GeoCoordinate is contained within this GeoBoundingBox.
Details, please check [here](https://developer.here.com/documentation/android-starter/3.15/api_reference_java/content/com/here/android/mpa/mapping/Map.html).

Btw, the starter edition has been deprecated. You should consider moving to other editions, like Premium edition.

Comment: Thanks, that solves the problem. I appreciate that the starter edition has been deprecated, but when I last looked the Lite edition didn't have the PositioningManager capability and this personal project doesn't justify the Premium edition.